# Background w. opacity gives unwanted borders

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a TabControl with two TabItems, which looks seamless in the visual designer in Visual Studio 2013 - but when I run my solution a border is created and I don't seem to be able to get rid of it. In the image it looks like it's all around the grid, but it's the border between the tab headers and tab content that concerns me.

If I replace the transparency from the background, and instead use a solid color, the problem disappears. It looks like it has to do with half transparency.

In the visual designer it looks like this:

[image: Visual Designer]

And the result when I build and run:

[image: Build and Run]

The code is somewhat straight forward, setting all BorderThickness to `0`.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HasSelectedBrush" Color="White" Opacity="0.65" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NoSelectedBrush" Color="White" Opacity="0.5" />

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="0" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Background="Transparent" />
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" Background="Transparent">
                                <ContentPresenter ClipToBounds="True" Margin="0" ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Margin="0" Background="{ StaticResource NoSelectedBrush }" BorderThickness="0">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="0, 20, 0, 20" />
                            </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{ StaticResource HasSelectedBrush }" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="MainViewGrid">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/Images/Background.jpg" />
            </Grid.Background>
            <TabControl Width="500" Height="400" Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="Transparent">
                <TabItem Header="Tab One" Width="250">
                    <controls:FirstTabControl />
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Tab Two" Width="250">
                    <controls:SecondTabControl />
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update**

After some more testing, I've concluded that it depends on the window size. It seems that the border comes from anti-aliasing, but setting `SnapsToDevicePixels` to true does not solve my problem.

Comment: I recommend to run Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to analyze this kind of problems.

Comment: Have you checked the ItemContainerStyle template. In Blend right click TabControl, Edit additional templates, edit a copy of ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: @modosansreves - Thanks, great looking tool!

Comment: Updated question, it looks like it depends on anti-aliasing. By resizing the window, I can make the border disappear. However, setting `SnapsToDevicePixels` does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No answer, just a refinement of the question.

Following the question I did a lot of experimenting, and I found another interesting fact.

Stack panel did not place continuously the Childs when it is in the TabControl!

Here's an example. In this code

Given this code:

```
<Grid Background="Black"  Width="150">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border Background="White" Height="50" />
        <Border Background="White" Height="50" />
        <Border Background="White" Height="50" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

But in TabControl, like:

```
    <TabControl Background="Black" Width="150" >
        <TabItem Header="Tab" >
            <StackPanel>
                <Border Background="White" Height="50" />
                <Border Background="White" Height="50" />
                <Border Background="White" Height="50" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

[image]

Why are there lines across their `Borders`?

Comment: i can't reproduce that behavior (WPF .Net4.5 W8.1) the only "Border" i became was from the black background but non of this gray lines

Comment: Interesting. my machin (Win7) at design time does not appear, but at runtime appears as pictured.

Comment: mhh maybe it is a baseStyle thing of the Border

Comment: i mean maybe the TabControl or TabItem has a style Resource which overrides the Basestyle and so you get this borders (you could use [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to dig into the running object)